# Use PostgreSQL NOT SIMILAR TO in Symfony Doctrine query builder

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am attempting to use PostgreSQL's [NOT SIMILAR TO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html) exclude a blacklist from the results of a query,

When I run the query in my repository method below:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('p');

$query = $qb
    ->select('p')
    ->from('CRMPiccoBundle:Person', 'p')
    ->where("lower(p.email) not similar to '(" . implode('|', $blacklist) . ")%'")
    ->getQuery();

return $query->getResult();
```

I get the following error:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]                                                                                                                
SELECT p FROM CRMPiccoBundle:Person p WHERE lower(p.email) not similar to '(abuse@|admin@|billing@|compliance@|devnull@)%' 

[Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]                                     
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 94: Error: Expected end of string, got 'to'
```

**However**, when I run this query against my local DB with PgAdmin it works.

How can I achieve this with Doctrine using the Symfony Doctrine Query builder (or similar)? I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('p');

$select = $qb
    ->select('p')
    ->from('CRMPiccoBundle:Person', 'p')
;

foreach ($blacklist as $key => $item) {
    $select
        ->where('lower(p.email) NOT LIKE :key'.$key)
        ->setParameter('key'.$key, "$item%")
    ;
}

$query = $select->getQuery();

return $query->getResult();
```

Comment: @crmpicco thanks for the edit, I don't keep an eye on that, because I only write the code without testing :D

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't think about lining up the `NOT LIKE`s like that. It makes perfect sense when I seen your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[`martin-georgiev/postgresql-for-doctrine` @ GitHub](https://github.com/martin-georgiev/postgresql-for-doctrine/) adds support for `REGEXP`, `SIMILAR_TO`, `NOT_SIMILAR_TO`, `JSON_GET_FIELD` and `CONTAINS` operators, among others.